# Managing helper death

Tags: python, emacs, rope, ropemacs, pymacs

I had installed Pymacs, rope, ropemode, ropemacs, and when I executed `pymacs-terminate-services`by accident, I couldn't save modified buffers. It first asked me - `The Pymacs helper died. Restart it? (yes or no)`. If I answered "yes", it threw - `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "There is no Pymacs helper!")`. If I answered "no", it threw:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pymacs.py\", line 258, in loop
    value = eval(text)
  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
")
```

I managed to work around by executing `pymacs-load`, loading `os` module, and answering yes to Pymacs helper restart question. The buffer was saved, but then I started to get another error everytime I saved the file:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pymacs.py\", line 258, in loop
    value = eval(text)
  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: major() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
")
```

This is my init-file:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/pymacs.el")
(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-autoload "pymacs")
(require 'pymacs)
 (pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
```

[Pymacs manual](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html#pymacs-auto-restart) describes death of Pymacs helper. It tells that I shouldn't close `*Pymacs*` buffer, because this kills the helper, and should also restart Emacs if helper is killed. This is unacceptable as I have a habit of closing all buffers from time to time and also rarely restart Emacs. I have several related questions now:

- What is the best way to handle Pymacs to minimize such problems? Is it possible to run Pymacs only when i work with Python and then safely terminate it again?
- What is `pymacs-terminate-services` for and should I ever run it?
- What should I do if I ever accidentally run `pymacs-terminate-services`? I'm especially interested in how to edit `before-save-hook` to make buffer saves possible without error messages.

Comment: Not tried it, but [this bit in the Pymacs/contrib/Giorgi/ dir](https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/blob/b4e462f52566ad51c18f5d65e1db32af1e24bc13/contrib/Giorgi/dotEmacs.py) seems relevant, maybe..?

Comment: A very detailed, grammatically correct question that hasn't received a conclusive answer... definitely deserving of a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I can think of is to use `kill-buffer-query-functions` hook to prevent `*Pymacs*` to be killed.  Like this:

```
(defun my-pymacs-saver ()
  (if (equal (buffer-name) "*Pymacs*")
      (yes-or-no-p "Really kill *Pymacs* buffer? ")
    t))

(add-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'my-pymacs-saver)
```

It will ask you if you really want to kill `*Pymacs*` buffer or not.  You can even make it impossible to kill from keybinds by this:

```
(defun my-pymacs-saver ()
  (if (equal (buffer-name) "*Pymacs*")
      (progn
        (message "NEVER kill *Pymacs*!")
        nil)
    t))
```

I use `pymacs-terminate-services` to forcefully reload all modules. I have a function similar to `pymacs-reload-rope` in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AntonNazarov.

Probably you can add `pymacs-terminate-services` to `kill-buffer-hook` (locally in `*Pymacs*` buffer) for more graceful termination.  But I am not sure.  For the rest of your question, I guess it's better to ask/request in the Pymacs [issue tracker](https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/issues).

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally kill the *Pymacs* buffer or execute `pymacs-terminate-services` you can recover the process by executing the following command and answering "yes" at the prompt.

```
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
```

You can modify your init-file function to allow for the restart to be called interactively with `M-x python-restart`. Restarting Pymacs in this manner will avoid the `TypeError: major()...` error.

```
(defun pymacs-restart ()
  (interactive)
  (pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-"))

(load "~/.emacs.d/pymacs.el")
(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-autoload "pymacs")
(require 'pymacs)
(pymacs-restart)
```